# C program — coding the figure given n when n is odd?

Tags: c

I have to display the following  figure (The two triangles intercept) for a n given by the user, where n is odd. The figure is in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVbUE.jpg

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

I already wrote this code, but I don't know how to give the n, where n is odd. And my code doesn't compile; it says: "In the fifth row, syntax error before for".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int n,i,k,m;

    for(m=0;m<2;m++)
        for  (i=1;i<=n;i++){ 
            if(m==0){    
                for(k = 1; k<=n-i; k++){        
                    printf("  ");      
                }   
            } 
        }
    for (k=1;k<2*i;k++){   
        printf("%s","*");   
        //printf("%d",i);
    }

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (k = 1; k<=i;k++)
        for (k=1;k<(n-i)*2;k++)
           for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {   
               printf("\n$"); 
           }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have proper indent in your actual program. You are missing an opening bracket after int main() and a closing bracket at the end.

Comment: Floris,I need to know how to put the odd n in printf ..thanks for that :)

Comment: This code has so many problems. Like `main()` is not being followed by `{}` and the `for` loop in 5th line is also missing `{}`.

Comment: if((n % 2) == 1) -> Odd.

Comment: Thanks but when I run it I only get ****** :/ :/

Comment: You have two consecutive loops `for (k = 1; k <= i; k++) for (k = 1; k < (n-i)*2; k++)` which is not going to work well.  The second loop will modify `k` and cause the first loop to stop after 1 iteration (probably — it depends on the values in `i` and `(n-i)*2`).

Comment: @SukritKalra It's valid to not have `{}` after a `for`, it will just use the next statement as the loop body (which here is the two `for` loops following it). Whether that is intentional or not is a different question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks , Jonathan. I can remove the bandages from my eyes now.

Comment: What is the question, really? Do you want to know how to check whether _n_ is odd? There are usually at least two obvious ways. Hint for the most obvious: there is an operator that returns the _rest of a division_.

Comment: @ajp15243: My apologies. I thought that a `for` loop followed by a `for` loop needed the curly braces since it meant many instructions following the initial loop. Just tested and it works fine, so that is not a valid error.

Comment: @SukritKalra No worries, that's why many people don't like omitting optional `{}` :).

Comment: Honestly, sir, just by looking at this code, determining whether N is odd is the least of your worries.

Comment: I am a lady not a sir.And my eyeballs are squirting out of my eyes ,because Ive been programming so much :/

Comment: @SdasdSdaf Your eyeballs are squirting out of your eyes? That's almost as disturbing as it is confusing.

Comment: They squirted and then came out of the eyes.

Comment: I think the word is sockets. Anyway, in case you're bored, [single-for-loop-no recursion](http://ideone.com/U1XN76). (and yes, I really should check my mallocs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAsterisk(int n, int length){
    int i, slen = (length - n)/2;
    for(i=0;i < slen;++i)
        putchar(' ');
    for(i=0;i < n;++i)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}
/* non-recursive
void printTriangle(int n, int length){//n isn't required as an argument
    int d= -2;
    for(; n < length + 1; n += d){
        if(n < 0) n += (d *= -1);
        printAsterisk(n, length);
    }
}
*/    
void printTriangle(int n, int length){
    if(n < 1) return;
    printAsterisk(n, length);
    printTriangle(n - 2, length);
    printAsterisk(n, length);
}

int main(void){
    int n;
    do{
        printf("input odd number:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while(n % 2 == 0);

    printTriangle(n, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You sir,are a f***** genius.Thank you.

Comment: I understood the logic,Floris.I learned it.Interesting fact : This is not a homework.

Comment: @SdasdSdaf  It may be good to try  the loop as the first policy.

Comment: Just because this site is called Stack Overflow doesn't mean that recursion should be used to solve every mundane, simple algorithm. There is absolutely no reason why you would need recursion for this.

Comment: I do not know, but it should put out another statement?

Comment: The standards for "*genius*" appear to have slipped... or been entirely abandoned.

Comment: you are free pretty and comment one by one to compliment.

Comment: Oh no! The answer actually contains complete code that compiles! All the people who watch C tags are running to hide.

Comment: I do not know well because not familiar with the English expression.

Comment: @SSHThis it's got nothing to do with whether the code is complete or whether it compiles... but whatever.

Comment: I think the code this answer provides is much more useful to the person who answered the original question more than taking abuse from people who like bashing the code, which happens more in C Questions on SO than in any other language.

Comment: Is It praise ? Thank you.
there isn't to say separately,  I don't think  recursion is difficult  and complex in this case.

Comment: I've also written non-recursive version reputation is so bad like recursive version somehow.

Answer (score 6):

First, the answer to *"how do I check whether an integer is odd"*: you simply divide by 2 and check if the remainder is 0 (even) or 1 (odd). In C and most related languages, this is what the modulo operator "%" does:

```
if ((n % 2) == 1) {
    // The number is odd.
}
```

But you should make sure that you read your *n* right at the start, because in the code that you have submitted, *n* is read in your second "for" loop before you have actually written something to it. And that means, *n* contains garbage at that point.

Comment: Pasting this in still leave's you with a mess though.

Comment: No problem. BTW, your compiler error might be because there's a `{` missing after "main" (but then, it does look like that's not the whole code? it's also missing `return` and main's `}`.

Comment: Obviously it has many logical errors and its not going to work.I will quit this thing and go work at Starbucks.

Comment: Yeah, you better start completely over with this one. Try to solve this in steps. Like, first solve the problem of how to print a single line with hardcoded values (for example, assume n=5 and you're printing the second line). Then you move on to solve this hole shape with hardcoded values, and _then_ you read it via scanf.

Comment: @WhozCraig Neat solution, but then the instructor asks her to explain the code at which point she'll be in trouble ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Good programming is to solve problems in the most simple way you can find. This particular algorithm is really fundamental stuff, thus you shouldn't end up with anything much more complicated than this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void print_chars (char symbol, int n)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", symbol);
  }
}

void print_triangle (int base_size, int height, bool pointing_up)
{
  int star_count = pointing_up ? 1 : base_size;

  for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
  {
    int spaces = base_size - star_count;

    print_chars (' ', spaces/2);
    print_chars ('*', star_count);
    print_chars (' ', spaces/2);

    printf("%\n");
    star_count += pointing_up ? 2 : -2;
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  print_triangle(7, 4, false);
  print_triangle(7, 4, true);
}
```

Note that the above code will behave strange if the triangle's base isn't in sync with its height - I left that out intentionally, feel free to improve the program further with such.